# How to retrieve a user with a deep query in Prisma Client?"

Tags: javascript, prisma

```
model Client {
  id          Int            @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt   DateTime       @default(now())
  email       String         @unique
  name        String?
  lastName    String?
  password    String?
  profile     ClientProfile?
  franchise   Franchise      @relation(fields: [franchiseId], references: [id])
  franchiseId Int
  Records     Record[]
}

model ClientProfile {
  id                      Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt               DateTime  @default(now())
  photo                   String?
  age                     DateTime?
  sex                     String?
  birthDate               DateTime?
  phone                   String?
  alternativePhone        String?
  documentType            String?
  documentNumber          String?
  taxIdentificationNumber String?
  frontPhotoID            String?
  IdPhotoBack             String?
  nationality             String?
  province                String?
  city                    String?
  note                    String?
  country                 String?
  address                 String?
  clientId                Int?      @unique
  client                  Client?   @relation(fields: [clientId], references: [id])
}
```

My goal is to retrieve a user with a specific franchiseId and a specific documentNumber. I'm attempting to achieve this using the Prisma Client query:

```
const client = await this.prisma.userClient.findUnique({
  where: {
    franchiseId: 1,
    clientProfile: {
      documentNumber: "23212123221"
    }
  }
});
```

i am use nodejs with prisma client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query would look something like this:

```js
  const client = await prisma.client.findFirst({
    where: {
      franchiseId: 1,
      profile: {
        documentNumber: "123",
      },
    },
  });
```

If you want to use `findUnique`, you need to pass atleast one unique attribute in the where clause.